# How to show user only part of records?

Tags: administration, sharing, user-management, sharing-rule, visibility

I have user profile named `SimpleUser`, and sObject `Account`

How to show only part of records from Accounts for this user?

Criteria for this value of record from another sObject related to `Account` and `User`.

Something like, `Territory`->`Account` Lookup and `Territory` ->`User` Lookup .

I have `Territory` with `Users` and `Accounts`, `Territory` has field `Name`.

How show to user records from `Accounts` that suitable `User.Territory equal Account.Territory?`

Comment: can you provide the default sharing settings for the 3 objects, and also how they are related. Master-detail, Lookup,...

Comment: Its Lookup relationships, everywere

Answer (score 0):

Apex based sharing rule can be the option. Refer the details and example in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)